# How to build an SDL C++ program for distribution?

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2013, sdl, sdl-2

I've been using C++ and SDL to create a program. When I build this program it works on my machine, but when I try to run it on another computer it says that all sorts of DLLs are required, and after including all the explicitly asked for DLLs the error becomes 
"The application was unable to start to start correctly (0xc000007b)."

What I'm asking is: how do I build this program in such a way that it will work on other computers. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop and SDL 2.0.3.

I'd be happy to answer any questions.

EDIT: Both computers were running 64 bit Windows 7.

EDIT 2: I included all the DLLs Dependency Walker suggested, but still got the "The application was unable to start to start correctly (0xc000007b)" error on the other machine.

Comment: Suggestion: try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).  This will tell you exactly what .dll's your SDL .exe needs to run on a different system.

Comment: Make sure you're not mixing 32 and 64 bit DLL's.

Comment: How do I check whether a DLL is 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

First include the SDL2.dll with the exe and other libs, then download the visual c++ redistributal 2013 and install it on that windows 7 machine, also make sure the build that you built wasn't a debug build